# Error al iniciar eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

al iniciar eclipse me aparece este error y no se a que se debe. He comprobado que la versión de Java sea de 64 bits y asi es. No se por que puede darme este fallo.

[image: Imagen]

Comment: ¿estás seguro tu eclipse es de 64bit?

Comment: Si, es de 64 bits, creo que el problema esta en las rutas del JAva